# Go command-line tool to do some simple byte manipulation

Tags: array, file, io, go, bitwise

I have some files containing 16-bit words in big-endian order, and a tool to process them that assumes little-endian order. I therefore need to swap the order of each pair of bytes in my files.

This is almost a one-liner in Python (`data[0::2], data[1::2] = data[1::2], data[0::2]`). However, since I need to do this manipulation often, I decided to write a standalone tool to do it. Also, for learning purposes, I decided to write this simple tool as my first Go program.

I look forward to any comments you may have about this code:

**byteswap16.go**

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io/ioutil"
import "os"

func parseArgs(args []string) (string, string, error) {
    if len(args) != 3 {
        return "", "", fmt.Errorf("Usage: %s infile outfile", args[0])
    }

    return args[1], args[2], nil
}

func byteswap16(data []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    length := len(data)
    if length%2 != 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Length is not a multiple of 2 bytes")
    }

    swapped := make([]byte, length)
    for i := 0; i < length; i++ {
        swapped[i] = data[i^1]
    }

    return swapped, nil
}

func run() error {
    infile, outfile, err := parseArgs(os.Args)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(infile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    swapped, err := byteswap16(data)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("%s: %v", infile, err)
    }

    if err := ioutil.WriteFile(outfile, swapped, 0666); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    if err := run(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

A couple of comments of my own:

1. As with the Python, the core algorithm is very little code, but it's written very differently - an explicit `for` loop over individual bytes rather than higher-level manipulation of many values at a time. I think I like the explicit loop more, because it's a more general solution - changing to `byteswap32` wouldn't require much more than changing `i^1` to `i^3`.
2. A common complaint about Go, but I don't really like the repetitive `if err != nil` in `run`. However, it does provide an obvious place to wrap `err` to add context, as is done after the call to the `byteswap16` function. If exceptions were used instead, the code would be more concise but the error message would be worse, because I don't think I would catch and re-throw to add context.

In general, would this be considered good-quality, idiomatic Go code?

Comment: Though a bit more explicit, it's a go oneliner, too (if you know you're just swapping 16 bytes): `data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3] = data[1], data[0], data[3], data[2]`. Alternatively, you can just swap pairs in a loop: `for i := 0; i<len(data); i+=2 { data[i], data[i+1] = data[i+1], data[i]} `

Answer (score 1):

Several things come to mind right away:

- I wouldn't make a custom `parseArgs` function, I'd use [`flag.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag#Parse). For just a pair of positional arguments it might be overkill but it makes it trivial to add more options, usage output, etc. And either way, it's better to only access `os.Args` from `main`
- Instead of `fmt.Fprint` to `os.Stderr` followed by `os.Exit` it's more idomatic to just use [`log.Fatal`](https://golang.org/pkg/log#Fatal) (or `Fatalf` or `Fatalln`).
- Avoid reading and writing entire files with `ioutil` if you can do work while streaming data. If the files are guarenteed to be small it's just a bad habit but if someone ever runs your tool on gigabytes or terabytes of data they'll be in for unpleasant surprise.
- In the same vein, I'd make your function API steam-able. Either by implementing an [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io#Reader) wrapper or by a function that takes an [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io#Writer) and an `io.Reader` (like [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io#Copy)).

  You could also implementing it as a [`transform.Transformer`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/text/transform#Transformer); but that's probably overkill, although perhaps an interesting exercise.
- Typically such command line tools in unix act as pipes, that is, if not given file arguments they read from `stdin` and write to `stdout`. Either you only work with stdin/stdout and make callers use shell redirection if they want to work to work on files or you make the filenames optional. Just initialise an `io.Reader` (or `io.ReadCloser`) variable to `os.Stdin` and an `io.WriteCloesr` variable to `os.Stdout`. Then when processing the arguments, if provided, open the relevant files and change the variables. Your choice if you use positional arguments as you've done or option arguments (as `dd` does and as I did below). Make sure to check for errors closing the destination.
- By the way, on unix you can use the standard `dd` command to do the byte swapping for you with the `conv=swab` operand:

  ```
  dd conv=swab if=someinput_file of=someoutput_file
  ```

  using files, or in a pipe like this:

  ```
  bigendian_command | dd conv=swab | littleendian_command
  ```

A quick stab at implementing it this way gave me the following.

(Also available at https://gist.github.com/dchapes/9d795a04e471319abbc5ff016afbbee9
the gist also has your version as revision 1, and a version using a function with an `io.Copy` like signature as revision 2).

`swab.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    log.SetPrefix("swab: ")
    log.SetFlags(0)
    infile := flag.String("in", "", "input `path`, blank for stdin")
    outfile := flag.String("out", "", "output `path`, blank for stdout")
    flag.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(flag.CommandLine.Output(),
            "Usage: %s [options]\n", os.Args[0],
        )
        flag.PrintDefaults()
    }
    flag.Parse()
    if flag.NArg() > 0 {
        flag.Usage()
        os.Exit(2) // To match the exit code flag.Parse uses.
    }

    var src io.ReadCloser = os.Stdin
    var dst io.WriteCloser = os.Stdout
    if *infile != "" {
        f, err := os.Open(*infile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        src = f
    }
    // Closing the input isn't strictly required in main
    // nor for stdio, but it's a good habit. No need to
    // check any error; we rely on Read reporting errors of interest.
    defer src.Close()

    if *outfile != "" {
        f, err := os.Create(*outfile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        dst = f
    }

    if _, err := io.Copy(dst, NewSwabReader(src)); err != nil {
        // Not this calls os.Exit so no defers get run
        // and we don't close the output either, not
        // an issue from main.
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if err := dst.Close(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

type SwabReader struct {
    r        io.Reader
    b        byte // extra byte, not yet swapped
    haveByte bool // true if b is valid
    err      error
}

// NewSwabReader returns an io.Reader that reads from r
// swapping adjacent bytes. The trailing odd byte, if any,
// is left as-is.
func NewSwabReader(r io.Reader) *SwabReader {
    return &SwabReader{r: r}
}

func (sr *SwabReader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if len(p) == 0 || sr.err != nil {
        return 0, sr.err
    }
    i := 0
    if sr.haveByte {
        // Copy in the previous saved byte.
        p[0] = sr.b
        i = 1
        //sr.haveByte = false // not strictly required
    }
    n, sr.err = sr.r.Read(p[i:])
    n += i
    p = p[:n]
    for i := 1; i < len(p); i += 2 {
        p[i-1], p[i] = p[i], p[i-1]
    }
    // Remove and save any non-swapped trailing odd byte.
    if sr.err == nil {
        if sr.haveByte = (n&1 != 0); sr.haveByte {
            n--
            sr.b = p[n]
            //p = p[:n] // not strictly required
        }
    }
    return n, sr.err
}
```

And a simple test, 
`swab_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "strings"
    "testing"
    "testing/iotest"
)

var readFilters = []struct {
    name string
    fn   func(io.Reader) io.Reader
}{
    {"", nil},
    {"DataErrReader", iotest.DataErrReader},
    {"HalfReader", iotest.HalfReader},
    {"OneByteReader", iotest.OneByteReader},
    //{"TimeoutReader", iotest.TimeoutReader},
}

func TestSwab(t *testing.T) {
    const sz = 32<<10 + 1
    cases := []struct{ in, out string }{
        {"", ""},
        {"a", "a"},
        {"ab", "ba"},
        {"abc", "bac"},
        {"abcd", "badc"},
        {strings.Repeat("\x01\x80", sz) + "x",
            strings.Repeat("\x80\x01", sz) + "x"},
    }
    var dst strings.Builder
    var r io.Reader
    for _, rf := range readFilters {
        for _, tc := range cases {
            r = strings.NewReader(tc.in)
            if rf.fn != nil {
                r = rf.fn(r)
            }
            dst.Reset()
            //t.Logf("swabbing %s %.16q", rf.name, tc.in)
            //r = iotest.NewReadLogger("<<< src", r)
            n, err := io.Copy(&dst, NewSwabReader(r))
            if err != nil {
                t.Errorf("swab on %s %q failed: %v",
                    rf.name, tc.in, err,
                )
                continue
            }
            if want := int64(len(tc.out)); n != want {
                t.Errorf("swab on %s %q returned n=%d, want %d",
                    rf.name, tc.in, n, want,
                )
            }
            if got := dst.String(); got != tc.out {
                t.Errorf("swab on %s %q\n\tgave %q\n\twant %q",
                    rf.name, tc.in, got, tc.out,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```